# AsyncTask to return a boolean? Best way to implement?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, networkonmainthread

I'm trying to check connection to the internet on Android (an actual connection, as opposed to network access) which causes `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. Because of this I'm trying to move it into an `AsyncTask`.

This is my `isConnected()` method:

```
if(!checkNetwork(parent)){
    return false;
}
if(!checkConnection(url)){
    return false;
}
return true;
```

Now, I check the connection by just using `if(isConnected())` but I'm getting the exception. So what I need to do is move the above method into an AsyncTask and retrieve the value it returns.

I thought perhaps I could make a global variable that'd keep track of it, but then I'm not sure if my value would be returned before or after the AsyncTask had set it.

I'm sure there are ways to do this, so I'm looking for ideas on how to do it. Any advice is appreciated!

**EDIT:** I've updated my code to use an AsyncTask, let me know if this looks better:

ConnectUtils.java:

```
public class ConnectUtils {

    private static boolean hasConnected, hasChecked;

    public boolean isConnected(Context parent, String url){ 
        hasChecked = false;
        this.new CheckURL(parent, url).execute();
        while(!hasChecked){ }
        return hasConnected;
    }

    private class CheckURL extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>{

        private Context parent;
        private String url;

        public CheckURL(Context parent, String url){
            this.parent = parent;
            this.url = url;
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params){
            if(!checkNetwork(parent)){
                return false;
            }
            if(!checkConnection(url)){
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result){
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            hasConnected = result;
            hasChecked = true;
        }
    }

    private static boolean checkNetwork(Context parent){
        ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager)parent.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if(conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null){
            NetworkInfo activeInfo = conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if(!activeInfo.isConnected() || !activeInfo.isAvailable()){
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private static boolean checkConnection(String url){
        boolean responded = false;
        HttpGet requestTest = new HttpGet(url);
        HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, 3000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, 5000);
        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
        try {
            client.execute(requestTest);
            responded = true;
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return responded;
    }
}
```

called via `if(!new ConnectUtils().isConnected(this, "http://google.com"))`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

here's a sample code:

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>()
{
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... p)
    {
        return isConnected();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result)
    {
        //this is code for the UI thread, now that it knows what is the result.
    }
}.execute();
```

Comment: Fixed the indentation for you.

Comment: you haven't "fixed" any indentation . it was fine before. it's called "whitesmiths code style" . read about it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#Whitesmiths_style . i've put the code back to what it was. i've worked with many companies, each has its own indentation rules. there is no "correct" way, so there is nothing to fix. since it's one of the basic ways to indent, if you are a developer, you should be able to read it easily.

Comment: @androiddeveloper So is a way I can do something like `boolean b = new AsyncTask().execute();` ? (I know that's wrong, but you should get what I mean)

Comment: @Zackehh9lives if you would make the UI thread to wait for a background thread, you might get an ANR message (app not responding) and that's an awful thing to have. that's because the UI thread should always have tiny and short tasks , in order to allow the user to interact with the app with no glitches. so , it is possible (not using the code you've written though) , but it's highly not recommended.

Comment: @androiddeveloper In terms of what I'm doing, the `isConnected()` boolean literally just checks if you're connected to a network via `ConnectionManager` and then pings a website if you are. Would you still go with AsyncTasks considering this?

Comment: @Zackehh9lives if it uses the internet , it should be run on the background thread. you cannot assume anything about the time it would take to finish this task, no matter what is done in a task that involves internet connection. even pinging could take time. for example, if you are on one side of the globe and you have a direct line to the other side of the globe (which you don't), it would still take time to reach it . the Earth's Circumference is ~40,075 km , while the speed of light is ~300,000 km/h . so, it would take ~0.135 of a second to get the result (send&receive).

Comment: @Zackehh9lives continuing my calculation, this is only if you have the perfect connection. you usually don't have it. usually there are more "stations" that your packets go through, and this takes time.

Comment: @androiddeveloper Thanks for the advice. Although, I'm not quite sure how to apply it in my situation efficiently without causing blocking anyway? I'll update my OQ to make it clearer.

Comment: @Zackehh9lives sadly i can't find which part you've updated, so i will simply offer my tip : don't block the UI thread. instead, while it checks for internet connection, you can show something to the user. for example a text and a spinning progress bar. when it's done , check the result and act accordingly (depends on your app).

Comment: I prefer [**the official Android style**](http://source.android.com/source/code-style.html), but if you want to use Whitesmith's that's fine with me. :)

Comment: @androiddeveloper Ah so that's the difference. Doing it on UI blocks the thread whilst doing it and showing a placeholder doesn't, but both cause the UI to stop advancing. This is what I wasn't understanding, I thought because the UI wasn't changing in either situation it didn't really make a difference.

Comment: @Zackehh9lives i don't understand, but i think you understand the problems and learnt something new today so i'm happy . :)

Comment: @androiddeveloper I just added my new code to my OQ, does that look more along the right lines? (just in terms of functionality)

Comment: @Zackehh9lives the "isConnected()" function is fishy. it shouldn't be run from the UI since it's blocking, so in order to call it, you need to create yet another background thread, which is a waste . it's also a bad type of blocking (should prefer this one instead : http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/thread-signaling.html ) .

Answer (score 1):

In your `AsyncTask`'s `onPostExecute` method, call a function in your activity to process the (now known) state of the connection. Until that method executes, your UI and/or internal logic should reflect that the state of the connection is unknown.

Answer (score 0):

Check the connection in the `doInBackground()` method of `AsyncTask<Url, Void, Boolean>`
Params = url, progress = void (nothing) and result is a boolean.

The `onPostExecute()` will return to the main thread of your application