# error httpclient run without thread

Tags: java, android

### Code:

```
public boolean CheckDeviceID(final Context context){
    try {
        //Looper.prepare(); //For Preparing Message Pool for the child Thread
        HttpClient httpclient;
        HttpPost httppost;
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters;
        httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        httppost = new HttpPost("http://"+Server+"/BusTicket/checkdevice/checkdevice.php");

        final TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        final String tmDevice, tmSerial, androidId;
        tmDevice = "" + tm.getDeviceId();
        tmSerial = "" + tm.getSimSerialNumber().substring(0, tm.getSimSerialNumber().length()-1);
        Log.d(null,"DeviceID="+tmSerial);
        postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("DeviceID", tmSerial));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent(); //Get the data in the entity
        String jsonstring = convertStreamToString(in);
        Log.d(null,"CheckDevice Reponse= "+ jsonstring);
        jsonstring = jsonstring.trim();
        if (jsonstring.equalsIgnoreCase("valid")){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.d(null,"CheckDevice error= "+ e.getMessage());
    }
    //Looper.loop(); //Loop in the message queue
    return false;
}
```

I have BroadcastReceiver and set alarm with every 10mins call this CheckDevice function, Check whether this device are registered in my database or not, if this function run in a thread is working, but can't return boolean with thread?!?

but if i run in OnReceive with this function, will cause the error, i m trying to print the error with `e.getMessage`  and returned error with `null`

any idea run the httpclient without thread? or let the thread return boolean ?

### Update

i m trying to use AsynTask to get the return boolean, and this code are inside `OnReceive`

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>()
                {
                    @Override
                    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... p)
                    {
                        return CheckDeviceID(context);
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result)
                    {
                        //this is code for the UI thread, now that it knows what is the result.
                    }
                }.execute();
```

But, in this code, how to get the return boolean?

Comment: You'll need to research AsyncTask. That'll do what you're after: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: @LokiSinclair Yes, i know and i did, but failed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18433040/asynctask-to-return-a-boolean-best-way-to-implement

Comment: @LokiSinclair Updated Code, Please review

Comment: That's a good start, but you now need to implement onTaskCompleteListener (or something like that - I'm away from a PC), and then override the onTaskComplete function to retrieve your boolean value. :)

Answer (score 0):

Two rules you must know about:
1- You must do any network operation in a different thread.
2- Don't put code that takes long time inside `onReceive` because receivers has small lifetime

You won't be able to return boolean but I think, among other options, you can use `SharedPreferences` or files to save the result of the thread and check this SharedPreferences value inside onReceive

Comment: dont put the takes long time inside Onreceive, but i have a question on stackflow, they ask me to use Broadreceive with AlarmManager. because in this broadreceive i m doing synchronization

Comment: if not using BroadReceive, what is better method to let the synchronization work until device shut down?

Comment: You got me wrong. Using broadcast receiver in you case is suitable I mean the action you want to do when  you receive inside onReceive() method. If it takes long time, then use thread inside onReceive like you already do now.

Comment: Have you tried saving the result in sharedpreferences and check for it inside onreceive before running the thread ? the next time onreceive gets called it should check this value and start the thread only if it is not set.

Comment: Yes, i know the sharedpreferences method, but i think it is not my prefer answer, i would like to use AsyncTask , but i dont know how to get the returned boolean

Comment: Where you want to return the result value ? if you mean you want it to return inside onReceive, this can not be done.

Comment: if using sharedprefences also is a problem, first time broadreceive check the device validation, need around 1 mins to send and reply from server, but the thread will threat as not valid device, because the result are havent reply from server

Comment: you can set different int values in the share pref. 0 -> not yet featced , 1 -> featced false , 2 -> featced true.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48903/discussion-between-c-y-and-msaudi)